# Update Common AngularJS HTTP Headers at Runtime

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, http-headers, runtime

How can I update the common HTTP headers at runtime from an AngularJS controller, e.g. `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']`? It seems `$httpProvider` can only be accessed from a config module, but I need to update common HTTP headers for all future requests from a controller, or a service called by the controller.

I can update the locally scoped headers for the next request by injecting `$http` into my controller, but I need to do update HTTP headers for all future requests, specifically for basic authentication.

Comment: Can't you just store in the service that makes all the http request the authorization to use and add them to all future request ?

Comment: @jackdbernier, AFAIK I can store an auth token in a `Session` service, but then I have to inject that service into every controller that does an HTTP request and set the common `$http` Authorization header many times. And somewhere I will forget. Can you provide any code samples?

Comment: I was thinking about wrapping your http request inside a Service. Then instead of injecting `$http` in your controllers/services you can inject your http wrapper. In this service you could have a method to set the authorization.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure exactly when it appeared in Angular, but a good 20 months later, you have the option to define default headers at runtime, directly on the $http object.

From [$http documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http): Setting HTTP Headers

```
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA=='
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this strategy once when I had to work with an API. I created an `XYZApiService` to wrap all the requests to that API.

Here's a simple example:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, HttpWrapper) {
  $scope.movies = [];
  HttpWrapper.setAuthorization('Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==');
  HttpWrapper.http({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'movies.json'
  }, function(data, status){
    $scope.movies = data;
  }, function(data, status){
    console.log('error', data, status);
  })
});

app.run();

app.factory('HttpWrapper', function($http) {
  var authorization = null;
  return {
    setAuthorization: function(auth){
      authorization = auth;
    },
    http: function(options, successCallback, errorCallback){
      if(authorization){
        options.headers = options.headers || {};
        options.headers.authorization = authorization;
      }
      console.log(options);
      $http(options).success(successCallback).error(errorCallback);
    }
  }
});
```

You can try it in Plunker here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/hr2Rvojic0asvWxSoalo?p=preview

Comment: Do you have to call `HttpWrapper.setAuthorization(...` in every controller, before every request?

Comment: No, a service in Angularjs is a singleton. I updated the plunker so you can see. So you will need to set it only the first time.